# Como enviar form ao selecionar checkbox?

Tags: php, html, input, checkbox

Tenho um formulário em html, enviando dados para o código php entanto utilizo o botão `input type="submit"` para enviar os dados e queria que ao clicar no checkbox já enviasse o form.
Segue abaixo o meu código:

```
    insira o código aquiecho '<tr>';
      echo '<form id="teste" action="banco.php" method="post"><td><input  id="check" name="bike'.$fetch['id'].'" type="checkbox"  onclick="document.getElementById("teste").submit()" value="on" class="confirmacoes"><a href="banco.php"> </a></td><form>';

      echo '<td >'.$fetch['id'].'</td>';
      echo '<td >'.$fetch['turno'].'</td>';


      echo '<td>'.$fetch['data'].'</td>';
      echo '<td>'.$fetch['tubetes_prod'].'</td>';
      echo '<td>'.$fetch['tubetes_caixadetubete'].'</td>';
      echo '<td>'.$fetch['logs_rebobinados'].'</td>';
      echo '<td>'.$fetch['logs_colados'].'</td>';
      echo '<td>'.$fetch['logs_acumulador'].'</td>';
      echo '<td>'.$fetch['rolo_produzido'].'</td>';

      echo '<td><a id="logo-container" href="'.$fetch['tipo_prod'].'" class="brand-logo"><img src="teste.png"  /></a></td>';
      echo '<td><a id="logo-container" href="'.$fetch['tipo_prod'].'" class="brand-logo"><img src="teste.png"  /></a></td>';
      echo '<td><a id="logo-container" href="'.$fetch['tipo_prod'].'" class="brand-logo"><img src="teste.png"  /></a></td>';
      echo '<td><a id="logo-container" href="'.$fetch['tipo_prod'].'" class="brand-logo"><img src="teste.png"  /></a></td>';
      echo '<td><a id="logo-container" href="'.$fetch['tipo_prod'].'" class="brand-logo"><img src="teste.png"  /></a></td>';
      echo '<td><a id="logo-container" href="'.$fetch['tipo_prod'].'" class="brand-logo"><img src="teste.png"  /></a></td>';
      echo '<td><a id="logo-container" href="'.$fetch['tipo_prod'].'" class="brand-logo"><img src="teste.png"  /></a></td>';
       $i++;
  };

  echo"<input type='submit' id='teste' name='teste'>";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coloca `onChange="this.form.submit()"` dentro da tag `<input />` do checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

Com o select é possível fazer

```
<select name="cidade" onsubmit="myFunction()">
           <option value="São Paulo">São Paulo</option>
 </select>
```

Com Checkbox acredito que abaixo da seleção você precise de um botão do tipo submit

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que você consiga fazer isso usando javascript. Segue um exemplo:

```
<input  id="check" name="bike'.$fetch['id'].'" type="checkbox" onclick="myFunction()" value="on" class="confirmacoes">
```

Você precisa declarar a função:

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("teste(id do seu formulario)").submit();
}
</script>
```

Comment: O que seria esse teste antes do id do meu formulario?

Comment: seu formulário esta com esse id, era apenas pra vc entender. Ficaria assim:  document.getElementById("teste").submit();